# Underscorejs _.where with wildcard

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

Have the following in an AngularJS controller:

```
$scope.initiatives = _.where($scope.initiatives, {i_status_id:'Open'});
```

It works fine to filter down the list based on a field if the property value is exactly 'Open'.

How do you use wildcard in the filter value so that it picks up 'Open - Pending' if I search for all the ones that contain 'Open'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) instead. Something like:

```
$scope.initiatives = _.filter($scope.initiatives, function(initiative){
    return initiative.i_status_id.indexOf('Open')>=0;
});
```

Comment: Thanks  I had hoped for '%Open%' .... does the return come back with "" if it's not found... and evaluates to a -1?